# Php echo where both " and ' are used in the string?

Tags: php, javascript, html, string

A string looks like this:

```
<form id="unban" method="post" action="unban.php?uid=<? echo $uID; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="" /> 
                <a onclick="document.getElementById('unban').submit();">UnBan</a>
                </form>
```

And i need this to be echoed out with a load of other variables (as there are if statements so i cant just put it outisde php tags) however I cant find a way to store it in a variable and use it in the echo. My echo looks like:

```
echo "<tr><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $banBool . "</td><td>". $status ."</td><td>" . $row['full_name'] . "</td></tr>";
```

where `$status` would be the form above depending on an if statement.

Is there a way to hold it as a string and still do this?

Also, just to clarify the javascript syntax requires 'target' and doesnt allow "target"

Comment: you can escape the quotes with \

Comment: Ewww, the `<?` short open tag! You should change that to `<?php`...

Comment: @animuson no you should not , <? is valid and will be activated by default in future versions of php.

Comment: @animuson whats wrong with just <? ? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write normal HTML within a PHP if-block - just close and re-open the PHP tags:

```
<?php
if($something == $somethingelse) {
    ?>
    <form id="unban" method="post" action="unban.php?uid=<?php echo $uID; ?>">
    ...
    </form>
    <?php
}
```

If you really need to hold it in a string, just make sure to escape whichever type of quotes are holding the string by **adding a backslash before each one**:

```
$status = '<form id="unban" method="post" action="unban.php?uid='.$uID.'">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="" /> 
            <a onclick="document.getElementById(\'unban\').submit();">UnBan</a>
            </form>
```

(Also notice you can't do an echo within a variable - just concatenate the string with the variable)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you output something more complex or need both types of quotes, you should use an [`HEREDOC`](http://php.net/HEREDOC) string:

```
echo <<<HTML

    <tr><td> $row[username] </td><td>
    $banBool </td><td> $status </td><td>  $row[full_name] 
    </td></tr>

HTML;
```

Note how you can eschew array key quoting here (behaves like a double quoted string).

If you need to prepare a string for Javascript usage, then additionally [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) might be sensible.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I like to echo with variables inside the strings is like so:

```
echo "This is a string with a {$variables["variable"]} in it. If I have to use another double-quote within this string I'll escape it with a \"backslash\".";
```

I usually completely avoid mixing single- and double-quotes (except when necessary, like your JavaScript function, to help reduce confusion.

Your HTML could be written like so:

```
echo "<form id=\"unban\" method=\"post\" action=\"unban.php?uid={$uID}\">
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"name\" value=\"\" /> 
    <a onclick=\"document.getElementById('unban').submit();\">UnBan</a>
</form>\n";
```

The resulting string that is echo'ed will have the natural characters and will have proper whitespace formatting.

Comment: I never do this, or recommend it.  It's very difficult to track down where the variables are, and often times, is completely wrong.  Variables usually need to be escaped to avoid XSS and what not.  Concatenation, or multiple echo parameters, are the way to go, in my opinion.

Comment: I find that this method makes it easier to track down where the variables are (Notepad++ highlights these in white instead of keeping them gray). How is it "often times" completely wrong? And how does this stop you from escaping your variables? You can either escape them when you assign them or you can break the string if you want to escape them inline.

Comment: In my opinion, it is best to escape things when used in the specific context that requires escaping.  I may want that data saved in a clean way for usage later, and escaping it while assigning means that isn't possible without making a second copy.  I choose to do something along the lines of: `echo 'Some text ', htmlspecialchars($somevar), ' some more text.';`  In my opinion, this makes it much more clear what is going on.

Comment: I suppose it's a difference in our typical usage. I never have a need to take user input and put it into HTML, so my usage usually saves me the few extra keystrokes and makes it stand out easier for me. To each his own, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use backslashes to escape quotes: \'

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just escape the quotes?

```
echo "\"", '\''; // "'
```

If that's not possible check out PHP's [heredoc and nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php) syntaxes. A third way to go would be closing the PHP block in the middle of an IF-statement and output the HTML directly.

Oh, you could also use [output-buffering](http://php.net/manual/de/ref.outcontrol.php) :-)